# how do i put an element in the top right corner of a header section?

Tags: html, css

how do i put an element in the top right corner of a header section?

Comment: Can we see your CSS, too? Have you tried [floating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) it?

Comment: If .header-section1 is position:relative, you can use absolute positioning on its children within it which would be one way to do this outside of floats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure this will do what you need.

```css
    #header-section1 {
      position: relative;
    }

    #floatright {
      position: absolute;
      top: 1px;
      right: 5px;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="header-section">
    <div id="header-section1">
         <h1><a href="http://esgr2.cspo.qc.ca/">École secondaire<br>Grande-Rivière</a></h1>
         <p>Commission scolaire des Portages-de-l'Outaouais</p>
         <div id="floatright">
             <p><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> ecole.secondaire.grande-riviere@cspo.qc.ca</p>
             <p id="phonenumber"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> (819)-682-8222</p>
             <ul>
                 <li><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
             </ul>
         </div>
    </div>
```

You may need to adjust the `top` and `right` values and you might also need to enforce a `padding-right` value for `#header-section1` to prevent the right-floated are from overlapping the left-aligned content.

Also, you probably should use classes instead of IDs for the CSS. It is highly recommended to *not* use IDs in your CSS.

Comment: Really not like that. Have you tried longer text in paragraph? Non-manually broken heading? Bigger font? Another font? Whatever? Think about another solution, `#floatright` id value should help you.

Comment: @pathner - using `float` is bad practice. My comments indicated using `padding` to avoid overruns. While you may not like this solution it is better then using floats. If you want a better solution that only works on newer browsers then consider grid or flex-box. But if you need older browser support then the above solution is quite useful.

Comment: Your claim that "using `float` is bad practice" seems overly generalized and deceptive. Please consider providing an explanation.

Comment: `Flex-box` and `grid` are both replacements and improvements for the difficult to use `float`. You may not agree with me, but if anyone working for me used `float` they would have to have an *extremely* good reason for it.